# in Google Sheets, I want Row 2 to always be empty to enter new data. And then after entered, it should be pushed down to Row 3

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to enter new data into Row 2 (across like 6 columns).  When I'm done entering data across the 6 columns, I'd like all of that data to be pushed down automatically to Row 3.

And have this happen every time.  So after a while, it would have hundreds of rows.

I always want row 2 to be where I enter the fresh data.

I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Do you want to do this using Google Sheets API with a programming language? Or use Google Apps Script?  Because I'm almost sure that this is impossible with the current features for Google Sheets.

Comment: Thx for reply.   Google Apps script would be best (and simplest) I'm assuming.  I'm just amazed there's not something that would do this built into the program.  Thx again for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When all cells of columns "A" to "F" of row 2 are manually embedded by the values, you want to move row 2 to row 3. And, you want to clear row 2.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, please set the sheet name, and save the script. When you use this script, please manually put the values to the columns "A" to "F" of row 2 on the sheet. By this, the script is automatically run.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const editRowNumber = 2; // This is from "enter new data into Row 2" of your question.
  const maxColumn = 6; // This is from "across like 6 columns" of your question.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.rowStart != editRowNumber || range.columnStart > maxColumn) return;
  const editRange = sheet.getRange(editRowNumber, 1, 1, maxColumn);
  const values = editRange.getValues()[0];
  if (values.filter(c => c.toString()).length != maxColumn) return;
  sheet.insertRowAfter(editRowNumber);
  editRange.moveTo(editRange.offset(1, 0));
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following situation is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This script is automatically run by the simple trigger of OnEdit. When you directly run this script, an error like `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.` occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thx again.  One question:  Is there a way to have the script run even if all columns don't have data entered into them.... could be activated if text entered into any cell along that row?    Oh, actually one last question / request... I have a dropdown option on some of the cells.   Any way to keep that automatically when the new row is added?   Please PM so I can send you a little starbuck coffee.

Comment: @all1word Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new 2 questions of `One question: Is there a way to have the script run even if all columns don't have data entered into them.... could be activated if text entered into any cell along that row?` and `Oh, actually one last question / request... I have a dropdown option on some of the cells. Any way to keep that automatically when the new row is added?`. I would like to support you.

Comment: @all1word But the issue of replying is new questions, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as a new question? Because when your initial question is changed by a comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Yes.  Thx.  I will post as a new question.  thank you!

Comment: @all1word Thank you for replying. I will check it when I saw your new question.